# Error while creating and executing a function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have a table as follows:

```
SCREENING_ID PLAN_ID THEATRE_ID SCREENING_DATE      SCREENING_START_HH24 SCREENING_START_MM60
           1       1          3 01.06.2015 00:00:00                    9                    0
           2       1          3 01.06.2015 00:00:00                   11                   30
           3       1          3 01.06.2015 00:00:00                   14                    0
           4       1          4 01.06.2015 00:00:00                   14                    0
```

I have to check whether a particular time slot is available or not.This function should contain the following input parameters: `plan_id_p`, `theatre_id_p`, `screening_date_p`, `screening_start_hh24_p`, `screening_start_mm60_p`. It should return `1` if having a time slot otherwise return `0`.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Func_is_time_available
(plan_id_p IN NUMBER,
 theatre_id_p IN OUT NUMBER,
 screening_date_p IN OUT DATE,
 screening_start_hh24_p IN OUT NUMBER,
 screening_start_mm60_p IN OUT NUMBER)

  RETURN NUMBER
    AS
    return_val NUMBER;

    CURSOR cr2 IS
    SELECT  plan_id,
            THEATRE_ID,
            SCREENING_DATE,
            SCREENING_START_HH24,
            SCREENING_START_MM60
    FROM screening s
    WHERE plan_id = plan_id_p and
          theatre_id=theatre_id_p and
          SCREENING_DATE=SCREENING_DATE_P and
          SCREENING_START_HH24=SCREENING_START_HH24_P and
          SCREENING_START_MM60=SCREENING_START_MM60_P;

    BEGIN
      OPEN cr2;
      FETCH cr2 INTO plan_id_p,
                     THEATRE_ID_P,
                     SCREENING_DATE_P,
                     SCREENING_START_HH24_P,
                     SCREENING_START_MM60_P;

      IF cr2%NOTFOUND THEN
        return_val := 1;
      ELSE
        return_val := 0;
      END IF;
    CLOSE cr2;
  RETURN return_val;
END;
```

And the execution part:

```
 DECLARE
  v_result NUMBER; 
 BEGIN v_result:=Func_is_time_available(plan_id_p=>1,
                                           theatre_id_p=>3,
                                           screening_date_p=>'1/JUN/2015',
                                           screening_start_hh24_p=>9,
                                           screening_start_mm60_p=>0);
 END;
```

But this is giving error as:

```
ORA-06550: line 18, column 44:
PLS-00363: expression '<expression>' cannot be used as an assignment target
```

Can anyone explain what my mistake is here?
I am using oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made changes to your code refer below

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Func_is_time_available
    (plan_id_p IN NUMBER,
     theatre_id_p IN  NUMBER,
     screening_date_p IN  DATE,
     screening_start_hh24_p IN NUMBER,
     screening_start_mm60_p IN  NUMBER)

      RETURN NUMBER
        AS
        return_val NUMBER;
    var1 number;
    begin
     SELECT  count(*) into var1
        FROM screening s
        WHERE plan_id = plan_id_p and
              theatre_id=theatre_id_p and
              SCREENING_DATE=SCREENING_DATE_P and
              SCREENING_START_HH24=SCREENING_START_HH24_P and
              SCREENING_START_MM60=SCREENING_START_MM60_P;
    if var1 >= 1 then -- count can be 1 or > 1
    return_val:= 1;
    else return_val:=0;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Works fine. However,It should return 1 if having a time slot otherwise return 0. So, the if-statement should be if var1=0 then return_val:=1 else return_val:=0.

Answer (score 0):

Make all parameters as `IN` instead of `IN OUT` and try.

Comment: It will not allow the values to be fetched into the cursor.

Comment: Your  parameters are defined as IN OUT.
That requires that you use a variable at that position when you call that procedure.
The variable is necessary, since the procedure wants to OUT a value into that variables. Any specific reason you need to use Cursor?

Comment: I thought using a cursor would simplify my problem. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion. :)